# How to filter the data from the beginning of the current year and the three previous years?

Tags: date, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have:

```
last3years_dates = ('2020-01-01 08:56:00', '2020-10-29 09:18:00')
df_NIRS = df_NIRS.where(F.col('RaisedDate').between(*last3years_dates))
```

'2020-01-01 08:56:00' and '2020-10-29 09:18:00' are placeholders. How can one filter from the beginning of this year, i.e '2020-01-01 00:00:00' to the 3 previous years '2017-01-01 00:00:00' without hardcoding it. Possibly use `current_timestamp()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.filter(
    F.col('RaisedDate').between(
        F.to_date(
            (F.year(F.current_timestamp()) - F.lit(3)).cast('string'), 'yyyy'
        ),
        F.to_date(
            F.year(F.current_timestamp()).cast('string'), 'yyyy'
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
df
.filter("dtCol between (current_timestamp - INTERVAL + 3 YEARS) AND date_trunc('Year',current_timestamp)")
.show()
```